# logstash with jdbc gets PsychParser error

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, logstash, jruby, logstash-jdbc

Background environment:
logstash using the microsoft jdbc driver to connect to sql server with integrated security.

When the jruby gets to PsychParser.java in 'parse' method, it throws an error:

```
<Psych:: SyntaxError: (<unknown>) 'reader' unacceptable character ' ' (0x0) special characters are not allowed in "'reader'", position 0 at line 0 column 0>
```

It used to work fine until the last week and suddenly it stop working and showing that error.

TNX for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I runned logstash-jdbc with

```
clean_run => "true"
```

configuration once, and now it seems to work fine again.